# Xcode 11 can't launch CarPlay audio application

Tags: xcode11, carplay

In Xcode 11 GM Version can't launch Car Play audio application in the simulator. 
Simulator stuck on the loading screen, then show "Unable to connect" error. Sometimes shows only black screen or crash on app launch.

While debugging, I see that methods from MPPlayableContentDataSource and MPPlayableContentDelegate won't fire. On Xcode 10 all work fine, so it's looks like some bug in new Xcode 11. Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks indeed.

[image: Connect issue]

Comment: It works if you build for iOS 11-12 simulators. For iOS13 the only way to test on real devices.

Answer (score 2):

I submitted a radar (FB7514196) to Apple.
You can see a copy of the radar here: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4997629368860672

Answer (score 1):

Just installed Xcode 11.3 and I'm still having this problem. Contacted Apple via the Feedback Assistant and the response was:

> Please ensure you're providing a prompt response to
>   MPPlayableContentDelegate and MPPlayableContentDataSource when you app
>   launches on the car screen. You have a few seconds after launch before
>   we show this timeout screen.

The first thing I do when starting the app is to set up this delegate and data source, so that's not the issue. Maybe something related to setting up CarPlay changed in the iOS 13 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 11 and Xcode 11.1 seem to contain a broken CarPlay implementation. Xcode 11.2 (beta-1) seems to work much better here. That said, the CarPlay simulator is finicky anyways and you should really use a real head unit to test your programs. I have found simply closing and reopening the CarPlay simulator to help with many issues, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Still the same issue here with XCode 11.2.1

Anybody found a solution?

The CarPlay simulator has always been a total disgrace - for years!